# onChange in React doesn't capture the last character of text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my render function:

```
  render: function() {
    return  <div className="input-group search-box">
              <input
                onChange={this.handleTextChange}
                type="text"
                value={this.state.text}
                className="form-control search-item" />
              <span className="input-group-btn"></span>
        </div>
   }
```

and I have this as my event handler:

```
   handleTextChange: function(event) {
     console.log(event.target.value);
     this.setState({
       text: event.target.value
     });
   }
```

The problem is that when I "save" an item, or console.log print the output, the last character is missing - for instance, if I enter "first", I'll get "firs" printed out, and there needs to be another key event to capture the last character. I've tried `onKeyUp` - which doesn't let me type anything in, and I've also tried `onKeyDown` and `onKeyPress`, which output nothing. 
What is happening here and why? and how can I get that last character to show up?

Comment: seems almost exactly like the example: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html - anything else modifying that scope?

Comment: what other react-functions does your component have? what's in `getInitialState()`?

Comment: How are you saving or `console.log`ing it exactly? Remember that `setState` is async: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674174/onchange-function-console-log-is-one-character-short

Comment: I had the same problem. I was setting state from event.target.value, and then assigned the new state to a data store. The last character didn't make it into the store. Instead I assigned event.target.value to both the state and the store. The last character makes it into the data store now.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When are you logging the state? Remember that `setState` is asynchronous, so if you want to print the *new* state, you have to use the callback parameter. Imagine this component:

```
let Comp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { text: "abc" };
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.text}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.printValue}>Print Value</button>
      </div>
    );
  },

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log("Value from event:", event.target.value);

    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    }, () => {
      console.log("New state in ASYNC callback:", this.state.text);
    });

    console.log("New state DIRECTLY after setState:", this.state.text);
  },

  printValue() {
    console.log("Current value:", this.state.text);
  }
});
```

Typing a `d` at the end of the input will result in the following being logged to the console:

```
Value from event: abcd
New state DIRECTLY after setState: abc
New state in ASYNC callback: abcd
```

Notice that the middle value is missing the last character. [Here's a working example](https://jsbin.com/lacuxi/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: DAMN. This was annoying

Comment: I totally forgot about the setState callback. Thanks for posting this. This has helped me on a similar but unrelated issue.

Answer (score 10):

Since setState() function in asynchronous, I used await.I achieved this using async and await, here is my code

```
render: function() {
    return  <div className="input-group search-box">
              <input
                onChange={(e) => {this.handleTextChange(e)}}
                type="text"
                value={this.state.text}
                className="form-control search-item" />
              <span className="input-group-btn"></span>
        </div>
   }
```

The handleTextCahnge function:

```
handleTextChange = async function(event) {

     await this.setState({text: event.target.value});
     console.log(this.state.text);
   }
```

Comment: async await should be working, but it did not for me in a Function Component _state hooks_. Then what I did was, called a function `onBlur` and checked the value.
Hope this would help someone.

Comment: Worked perfectly -- took some time to figure this one out. What is considered best practice here? Most other answers involved either (1) dispatching an event to prompt a change, or (2) wrapping this in a handle function.

Answer (score 8):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setUserInput(e.target.value);
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        //here you will have correct value in userInput 
    },[userInput])

    return (
        <div>
             <input onChange={changeHandler} value={userInput}></input>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 7):

Since React v.16.8 react hooks can be helpful.
I would recommend useState AND useEffect.
The Example is in React Native, however it should show how to work with the useEffect. More information about useEffect: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export interface Props{}
 
const InformationInputs: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [textInputs, setTextInputs] = useState("");

  const handleValueChange = () => {
    console.log(textInputs);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleValueChange();
  }, [textInputs]);

return (
    <TextInput
    placeholder={'Text'}
    onChangeText={(value: string) => { setTextInputs(value) }}
    />
);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

setState() function in asynchronous. Without using callback you can use another auxiliary variable to store and use the updated value immediately. Like :

```
export default class My_class extends Component{
constructor(props)
{
super(props):
this.state={
text:"",
};
this.text="";
}
 render: function() {
    return  <div className="input-group search-box">
              <input
                onChange={this.handleTextChange}
                type="text"
                value={this.state.text}
                className="form-control search-item" />
              <span className="input-group-btn"></span>
        </div>
   }

handleTextChange: function(event) {
     console.log(event.target.value);
     this.text = event.target.value;
     this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
     });
   }
```

You will get your updated value in this.text variable immediately. But you should use this.state.text to show text in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing to the console before setting the state. Write your console log after the state is set. It will show the full text. (I had the same problem)

```
handleTextChange: function(event) {
     **console.log(event.target.value)**


     this.setState({
         text: event.target.value
     });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Since **React v. 16.8** you can use react hooks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {

    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setUserInput(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
             <input onChange={changeHandler} value={userInput}></input>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It works great for me.

Comment: It is true that it captures `target.value`, but it still won't capture the very last character as OP needed.