# Input onChange and wrong state output in console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React.
There is a component. When I write text to the input (for example, the text: "stackoverflow"), onChange fires, "stackoverflow" is written to the state (That's right), but for some reason console.log displays "stackoverflo" for me (without last letter).

Why is this happening?

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

class SearchPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {    
    // let term = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });    

    console.log(this.state.value);
    // this.props.searchUpdate(this.state.value);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control search-input"
        placeholder="Test"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SearchPanel;
```

Comment: `setSate` is asynchronous, You need to use the async callback  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088482/onchange-in-react-doesnt-capture-the-last-character-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the state in React acts like an `async` function.
Meaning that the when you set the state and put a `console.log` right after it, it will likely run before the state has actually finished updating.

Which is why the `setState` function in class components accepts an optional second parameter which is a callback function that will automatically run after the state has finished updating.

**Example:**

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {    
  this.setState({ 
     value: event.target.value
  }, () => { 
     console.log(this.state.value);
  });
};
```

This `console.log` will run only after the state has finished changing and a render has occurred.

- **Note:** this is only relevant for class components, it's a different story in functional components.

Check the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more info.